# How to disable alt focusing menu on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio (Not VSCode), and am trying to set some keybindings to `alt+`, but I can't because `alt` automatically focuses on the menubar, so things like `alt+w` open `Window`. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently if you rebind the `alt+` menu focus shortcuts it will just manually override it, no issues. `Alt+W` for example only focuses on `Window` if `Alt+W` is not already binded to something else. The moment you add a custom shortcut for `Alt+W` the menu focus goes away.

Nice.